# How can I set focus on a TextField in Flutter without opening the keyboard?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to achieve focus on a TextField in Flutter without automatically opening the keyboard. I've followed the usual approach by using the focusNode parameter, but the keyboard opens automatically when I set the focus. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Here's what I've tried so far:

I created a FocusNode instance:

```
FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
```

In the TextField widget, I set the focusNode parameter to the created FocusNode:

```
TextField(
  focusNode: _focusNode,
)
```

To prevent the keyboard from opening automatically, I tried using FocusScope. However, the keyboard still opens when I call the requestFocus function:

```
void requestFocus() {
  _focustNode.RequestFocus();
}
```

Am I missing something or is there an alternative approach to achieve the desired behavior? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!